# Add first and last number of a list

Tags: python

I am asked to add the first and last numbers in a list. This is what I came up with:

```
def addFirstAndLast(x): 
    return x[0] + x[-1]
```

But when I run the code, i get an error that says:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I can't find the problem though and when I searched for this question, the answers were equal to my code.

Maybe it has to do with the test cases:

1. `addFirstAndLast([2])`
2. `addFirstAndLast([2, 2, 3])`
3. `addFirstAndLast([])`

Can you help me please?

Comment: The last doesn't have an element 0.

Comment: This error "IndexError: list index out of range" means you try to access to a value but it not in your array. If you have 10 elements. The first one have index 0 and the last one 9.

Comment: Do you understand the expression `x[0]`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if your list is empty or not.

```
def addFirstAndLast(x): 
    return (x[0] + x[-1]) if x else 0
```

Comment: Thanks man, I really appreciate it. It did not quite work, because the program would add 2 twice in the first test case, so I came up with:<br/>`if x and len(x) == 1:
  return x[0]
 elif x and len(x) > 1:
  return (x[0] + x[-1])
 else:
  return 0`

Comment: But it did that before too.

Answer (score 0):

The last test case passes an empty list. An empty list has neither `[0]` nor `[-1]` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, in your 3rd case there are no items, hence no relevant index.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is empty, then you do not have the first and the last elements. Try the following to solve your problem:

```
def add_first_and_last(x):
    if x:
        return x[0] + x[-1]
    else:
        return 0  # Or whatever you want
```

You can also try:

```
def add_first_and_last(x):
    return x[0] + x[-1] if x else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In your last case 3. `addFirstAndLast([])` isnt there any index at [0] and [-1]

because the list is empty!

So you should make an example `if x == []: return x`